# Ubuntu 18.04 guests which cloned by virtualbox have the same ip but different mac address in NAT network

Tags: networking, virtualbox, dhcp, clone

I tried to build a group of Virtual machine in Virtualbox, and connect them with NAT network. The main information shows as below:

```
The Virtualbox version: 6.0.12
The Ubuntu guest version: ubuntu-18.04.2
The NAT network info:
     NetworkName:    natnet22
     IP:             192.168.13.1
     Network:        192.168.13.0/24
     IPv6 Enabled:   No
     IPv6 Prefix:    fd17:625c:f037:2::/64
     DHCP Enabled:   Yes
     Enabled:        Yes
     loopback mappings (ipv4)
             127.0.0.1=2
```

When I finish creating an Ubuntu machine, the DHCP server maybe assign ip `192.168.13.4` for it. But when I cloned the machine and I change the mac address of the cloned one. The DHCP server still assign ip `192.168.13.4` for the cloned one.

Why the cloned Ubuntu one get the same ip with source? I need them have different ip in the NAT network to control them.  Please help me solve the problem.

Comment: Hi, you forgot to ask the question.  Which bit puzzles you?

Comment: Why the cloned Ubuntu one get the same ip with source? I need them have different ip in the NAT network to control them.

Comment: Could it be that the dhcp server is the issue? It is the one deciding the ip address to assign to the mac address.  You usually configure a "range" of IPs and it will always assign the first available ip addr.

Answer (score 8):

In newer Ubuntu versions, netplan is used for configuring the network. The file /etc/machine-id is used to create the DHCP identifier by default, rather than using the MAC address of the NIC.

When a Ubuntu system is cloned, the cloning process may change the MAC address of the NIC but it typically doesn't automatically change /etc/machine-id.

On your two systems, you can compare the contents of /etc/machine-id and they're probably the same.

You have two options:

1. Change the machine-id on at least one of the servers (huangjunpo's answer)

   ```
   user@host:~$ cat /etc/machine-id
   d8dcd93cd8bffce0f7ed73875eb5be3a

   user@host:~$ sudo rm /etc/machine-id
   user@host:~$ sudo systemd-machine-id-setup
   Initializing machine ID from random generator.

   user@host:~$ cat /etc/machine-id
   4b603489b08541ce9127791047081f46
   ```
2. If using netplan, change the way netplan constructs the client identifer for DHCP to use the MAC address by adding `dhcp-identifier: mac` to your netplan config file in `/etc/netplan`. Add it under any interface you need to, and be careful of indentation in the yaml file.
   (see [netplan.io - examples](https://netplan.io/examples#integration-with-a-windows-dhcp-server))

   ```
   user@host:~$ cat /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
   # This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
   network:
     ethernets:
       enp3s0:
         dhcp4: true
         dhcp-identifier: mac
     version: 2
   ```

After making this edit, you will have to apply it to make it have effect.

```
sudo netplan apply
```

Note that `/var/lib/dbus/machine-id` is linked to `/etc/machine-id`.

```
user@host:~$ ls -l /var/lib/dbus/machine-id
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 May  8 20:30 /var/lib/dbus/machine-id -> /etc/machine-id
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following commands on cloned vm:

```
sudo ip address flush scope global
sudo dhclient -v
```

Comment: This worked, but only temporarily.  Upon reboot the VM went back to the previous IP.

Answer (score 1):

Run below commands in bash shell. Use machine's id as identifier.

```
sudo rm /etc/machine-id
sudo systemd-machine-id-setup
```

Comment: Can you explain why this will solve OP's question, even if it's a sentence or two?

Comment: This worked for me.  I tried Alexandre's solution below which worked temporarily but this persisted through a reboot of the VM.